# How to insert into a complete B+ tree?

Tags: tree, b-tree

I can't find any examples on how to insert into a B+ tree when every position is filled. I have a B+ tree M=5 and L=5 and the tree is complete with values from 1-25 inserted. If I wanted to insert 26 into the tree, how would I go about splitting the tree up so I can accommodate the 26?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [B+Trees.pdf](http://baze.fri.uni-lj.si/dokumenti/B+%20Trees.pdf) which shows a detailed example of an B+Tree including the insert into full leafs.